# subset by counting the number of times 0 occurs in a column after groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have some typical stock data. I want to create a column called "Volume_Count" that will count the number of 0 volume days per quarter. My ultimate goal is to remove all stocks that have 0 volume for more than 5 days in a quarter. By creating this column, I can write a simple statement to subset Vol_Count > 5.

A typical Dataset:

```
Stock     Date      Qtr     Volume
 XYZ     1/1/19   2019 Q1     0
 XYZ     1/2/19   2019 Q1     598
 XYZ     1/3/19   2019 Q1     0 
 XYZ     1/4/19   2019 Q1     0
 XYZ     1/5/19   2019 Q1     0
 XYZ     1/6/19   2019 Q1     2195
 XYZ     1/7/19   2019 Q1     0
 ... ... and so on (for multiple stocks and quarters)
```

This is what I've tried - a 1 liner -

```
df = df.groupby(['stock','Qtr'], as_index=False).filter(lambda x: len(x.Volume == 0) > 5)
```

However, as stated previously, this produced inconsistent results.

I want to remove the stock from the dataset only for the quarter where the volume == 0 for 5 or more days.

Note: I have multiple Stocks and Qtr in my dataset, therefore it's essential to groupby Qtr, Stock.

Desired Output: 
I want to keep the dataset but remove any stocks for a qtr if they have a volume = 0 for > 5 days.. that might entail a stock not being in the dataset for 2019 Q1 (because Vol == 0 >5 days) but being in the df in 2019 Q2 (Vol == 0 < 5 days)...

Comment: What is the desired result.

Comment: updated in my question. @pygo

Comment: @busybear thank you for your comment, you're right, i had the right inequality in my original code and just wrote it wrong here.

Comment: I think you just need to change the direction of your inequality to less than 5.  You want the value of your filter to return True for records  you want to keep.  So, for each group passed into `filter`,  you check the condition, if the results evual as True it keeps all records in that group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df['Volume'].eq(0).groupby([df['Stock'],df['Qtr']]).transform('sum') < 5]
```

Details.

1. First take the Volume column of your dataframe and check to see if
   it zero for each record.
2. Next, group that column by 'Stock' and 'Qtr' columns and get a sum of each True values from step 1 assign that sum to each record using `groupby` and `transform`.
3. Create boolean series from that sum where True if less than 5 and
   use that series to boolean index your original dataframe.

Comment: can you elaborate what exactly is happening here? @Scott Boston. Thank you, i will try it out!

Comment: yes, this is nice. :) I was trying with value_counts, didnt look good. :)

Comment: Nice one Scott as always.

Comment: Thanks anky_91 and pygo.